# What is the Objective-C way of getting a nullable bool?

Tags: objective-c, types, logic, boolean

How should I go about getting a bool value that I can assign true, false and nil to in Objective-C? What is the Objective-C way of doing this? Much like C#'s Nullable.

I'm looking to be able to use the nil value to represent undefined.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An `NSNumber` instance might help. For example:

```
NSNumber *yesNoOrNil;

yesNoOrNil = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]; // set to YES
yesNoOrNil = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];  // set to NO
yesNoOrNil = nil; // not set to YES or NO
```

In order to determine its value:

```
if (yesNoOrNil == nil)
{
    NSLog (@"Value is missing!");
}
else if ([yesNoOrNil boolValue] == YES)
{
    NSLog (@"Value is YES");
}
else if ([yesNoOrNil boolValue] == NO)
{
    NSLog (@"Value is NO");
}
```

On all Mac OS X platforms after 10.3 and all iPhone OS platforms, the [`-[NSNumber boolValue]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000178-boolValue) method is guaranteed to return YES or NO.

Comment: Agreed that this is the closest way of doing it natively, but I hate having to do it this way.  It leads to hard-to-spot bugs if a dev forget that the property is an `NSNumber*` and assumes it's a `BOOL`, in which case they test for `if (yesNoOrNil)` and it gives incorrect results without any warning.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to use some class for that,  e.g. wrap bool to `NSNumber` object.

Comment: +1 You certainly don't *need* to use a class, but it's the best way.

Comment: So, like... how do you do it?